# Does multi-classing into a martial class make you a member of martial class?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, multi-classing

> A character who has taken a class-specific multiclass feat counts as a member of that class for the purpose of meeting prerequisites for taking other feats and qualifying for paragon paths.

As a member of a martial class via a multi-classing feat, are you eligible for feats that can only be taken by martial classes? For instance, could a dwarven warlock, who took "Twilight Adept", gain access to this feat:

> Resilience of Stone
>
> Prerequisite: Dwarf, any martial class
>
> Benefit: You can use your second wind as an immediate interrupt when you are damaged by an attack.

Or is your class Warlock, and only Rogue for the purpose of rogue feats?

Comment: Good question, I'd like to know for my Dwarf Cleric/Warlord.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's a [thread on the WotC boards](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/28708605/MC_feats_and_classes_with_multiple_power_sources) from Nov '11 discussing a very similar question.

The rules themselves are apparently a bit unclear about the issue, and there is a PHB FAQ (see [here, #33](http://wizards.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1396/%7E/faq-for-the-player%27s-handbook!)) stating that you **don't** gain the other class's role by taking a MC feat:

> **33. Does taking a fighter multiclass feat qualify you for feats and paragon paths that require the defender role?**
>
> No, you do not gain the role of the class that you multiclass into.

However, the consensus on pretty much the whole board (and the official character builders) seems to clearly favor the obvious solution:

- **A:** fighter is a martial defender
- **B:** taking the fighter MC feat makes you a fighter for feats, paragon paths, etc
- **A + B:** if you take the fighter MC feat you are a member of a martial class and have the defender role for all stated purposes